# How to download an XML without the browser opening it in another tab

Tags: xml, browser, download, href

I have an xml file to be downloaded.
As you all know when i give the below link

```
<a href="some.xml">Downlad XML</a>
```

The XML will open in a new tab displaying it.
However I would like to know if there is a way, this can downloaded like other files such as a .zip file

Comment: Need to be done on the server side. Do you have access to the server side code, and if so is it PHP or what?

Comment: Are you the client or the server? Your question is quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 17):

After trying a lot of solutions, This worked for me.

Try to provide a dummy argument to the file link as shown below.

```
<a href="http://link/to/the/file.xml?dummy=dummy" download>Download Now</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. The `download` attribute was all I needed, at least for Chrome 47. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Caution: as of 8/22/2016, download is not supported in Safari browsers :/  See http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer since it doesn't involve any other language

Answer (score 16):

There's an HTTP header called Content-Disposition, which is defined in [RFC1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt) as follows:

> ### 2.1  The Inline Disposition Type
>
> A bodypart should be marked `inline` if it is intended to be 
>   displayed automatically upon display
>   of the message. Inline bodyparts should be presented in the order in
>   which they occur, subject to the
>   normal semantics of multipart messages.
>
> ### 2.2  The Attachment Disposition Type
>
> Bodyparts can be designated
>   `attachment` to indicate that they are
>   separate from the main body of the
>   mail message, and that their display should not be automatic, but
>   contingent upon some further action
>   of the user. The MUA might instead
>   present the user of a    bitmap
>   terminal with an iconic representation
>   of the attachments, or,    on
>   character terminals, with a list of
>   attachments from which the    user
>   could select for viewing or storage.

In order to put the header message on the xml file, you'd need the access to the server-side. For example using php's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function you could write something like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some.xml"');
```

If you don't have access to the server-side, you could try the following JavaScript trick that I found Googling (not sure if it would work):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'some.xml');">Save this page</a>
```

Comment: Is this supported by all browsers?

Comment: I can't guarantee *all* browsers, but it should work on most browsers if they respect HTTP.

Answer (score 6):

I found that just right clicking on the web browser and selecting "Save Page As..."  does the work.

Comment: OK - this needs to be upvoted about 80 times!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Mohd's solution above, I was able to use the download attribute as specified by W3 here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp. A cool trick about going this route is that you can specify what you want the downloaded filename to be, if it is different from the filename on the server.

```
<a href="http://link/to/the/file.xml" download="downloadedfilename.xml">XML Download Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like:

```
private function sendXml($xml, $label) {
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $label . '.xml"');
        echo ltrim($xml);
        ob_flush();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my VBA solution. The macro will download the XML file, save it in macro file's folder and inform the user once the process has been completed:

```
Sub SaveXMLFromWeb()

Dim XDoc As Object
Dim XMLpath As String, outPath As String

XMLpath = "http://example.com/examplefile.xml" 'change to your URL
outPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\yourFileName.xml" 'change output file name

Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

With XDoc
    .async = False
    .validateOnParse = False
    .Load (XMLpath)
    .Save (outPath)
End With

MsgBox ("XML file has been downloaded and saved in the following location:" & String(2, vbLf) & outPath)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 'download' attribute in the anchor tag

```
<a href="some.xml" download >Downlad XML</a>
```